# How to redirect all http traffic to https in Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a simple containerized web app (Nginx serving HTML and Javascript) that I deployed to Google Cloud Run.

The problem is, I can't seem to force HTTPS connections even though I already verified and updated the DNS records to do so. A user can still access the unsecured http endpoint of my Cloud Run application if they wanted to.

How to set up a Google Cloud Run service that forces or redirects users to use HTTPS?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're observing here.  You can only do HTTP or HTTPS over a single port, not both at the same time.

Comment: @DougStevenson Cloud Run could potentially allow users to force HTTPS by redirecting all http requests to https.

Comment: Beshoy, I edited the question a bit to take out the irrelevant parts let me know if it loses meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LB sends a header called `X-Forwarded-Proto` that contains either `http` or `https` so you can easily redirect with `301 Moved Permanently` in case you detect that.

Sample for the edited question with Nginx:
http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/10/28/always-on-https-with-nginx-behind-an-elb/

Example Go code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        if request.Header["X-Forwarded-Proto"][0] == "http" {
            http.Redirect(writer, request, "https://" + request.Host + request.RequestURI, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("Request: %+v, headers: %+v \n", request, request.Header)

        writer.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil)
}
```

Comment: No control over LB since essentially Cloud Run is a Knative Paas.

Comment: You don't need to control anything. These headers are sent to you by the LB, so all you need to do is return 301 redirect whenever you detect that

Comment: My mistake. I should have specified in my question that the only code running in the container is transpiled javascript. This answer is something I could work to implement.

Comment: In that case, the container must have some HTTP server running that's serving files. You can use Nginx or other servers to detect such configuration and redirect as well

Comment: I added that I'm using Nginx to my initial question. That seems easier to accomplish.

Comment: http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/10/28/always-on-https-with-nginx-behind-an-elb/ line 27 and 34-36 looks like they have the answer